# Property "com.apple.security.application-groups in" not working in device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have an application in that .entitlement file, I set **com.apple.security.application-groups** property and now application is not running in my iPad, with the following error message:

`The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.(0xE8008016)`.

Comment: are you sure that your iPad is included in the provisioning profile ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8850695/977094 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12802923/977094

Comment: after you set the groups property you need to regenerate the profile with the said group

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update any capability you need to generate new provision profiles. Reason is your app id contain those capabilities and whenever you update your app id capabilities you old provision does not contain new changes related to your app id. An attached image should app id contain group capabilities, so after adding this capability you should update your provision profile to see the effect inside provision profile.[image]